# Calculate avg() within laravel model and pass it to controller

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to calculate avg in laravel using three table joins I've joined the tables perfectly and got the response from it but now I want to calculate the avg as well as count from the response I have got and then pass it to API response what should I do to achieve this?

Query i have tried

`$individualScore= StatisticsMaster::with(['ratings',])->where('ratingsFor',$request->profileId)->get();`

StatisticsMaster.php

```
public function ratings() {
    return $this->hasMany(StatisticsChild::class,'statisticsMasterId','statisticsMasterId')->with('score');
}
```

StatisticsChild.php

```
public function score() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Skill::class,'skillId','skillId');
}
public function getSkillNameAttribute(){
    return $this->score->skillName;
}
```

DB Structure I have

tblSkills

```
->skillId
->skillName
->skillStatus
```

tblStatisticsMaster

```
->statisticsMasterId
->ratingsFor
->ratingsBy
->status
```

tblStatisticsChild

```
->statisticsChildId
->skillId
->statisticsMasterId
->individualScore
->statisticsStatus
```

I have got this response

```
{
  "meta": {
    "code": "200",
    "message": "Skill Fetched Successfully."
  },
  "data": {
    "skills": [
      {
        "statisticsMasterId": 1,
        "ratingsFor": 1,
        "ratingsBy": 6,
        "score": 60.8,
        "ratings": [
          {
            "skillId": 1,
            "individualScore": 86,
            "statisticsStatus": 1,
            "skillName": "Shooting"
          },
          {
            "skillId": 2,
            "individualScore": 70,
            "statisticsStatus": 1,
            "skillName": "Dribbling"
          },
          {
            "skillId": 3,
            "individualScore": 54,
            "statisticsStatus": 1,
            "skillName": "Passing"
          },
          {
            "skillId": 4,
            "individualScore": 44,
            "statisticsStatus": 1,
            "skillName": "Defense"
          },
          {
            "skillId": 5,
            "individualScore": 50,
            "statisticsStatus": 1,
            "skillName": "Good Teammate"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "statisticsMasterId": 2,
        "ratingsFor": 1,
        "ratingsBy": 2,
        "score": 52,
        "ratings": [
          {
            "skillId": 1,
            "individualScore": 50,
            "statisticsStatus": 1,
            "skillName": "Shooting"
          },
          {
            "skillId": 2,
            "individualScore": 50,
            "statisticsStatus": 1,
            "skillName": "Dribbling"
          },
          {
            "skillId": 3,
            "individualScore": 60,
            "statisticsStatus": 1,
            "skillName": "Passing"
          },
          {
            "skillId": 4,
            "individualScore": 50,
            "statisticsStatus": 1,
            "skillName": "Defense"
          },
          {
            "skillId": 5,
            "individualScore": 50,
            "statisticsStatus": 1,
            "skillName": "Good Teammate"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

and the response I want.

```
    {
      "meta": {
        "code": "200",
        "message": "Skill Fetched Successfully."
      },
      "data": {
        "skills": [
          {
            "statisticsMasterId": 1,
            "ratingsFor": 1,
            "ratingsBy": 6,
            "score": 56.4,
            "ratings": [
              {
                "skillId": 1,
                "individualScore": 86,
                "statisticsStatus": 1,
                "skillName": "Shooting"
              },
              {
                "skillId": 2,
                "individualScore": 70,
                "statisticsStatus": 1,
                "skillName": "Dribbling"
              },
              {
                "skillId": 3,
                "individualScore": 54,
                "statisticsStatus": 1,
                "skillName": "Passing"
              },
              {
                "skillId": 4,
                "individualScore": 44,
                "statisticsStatus": 1,
                "skillName": "Defense"
              },
              {
                "skillId": 5,
                "individualScore": 50,
                "statisticsStatus": 1,
                "skillName": "Good Teammate"
              }
            ]
          }
       ]
    }
 }
```

where all the individual score contains the avg of all the ratings I'm using eloquent I want to do this in eloquent itself. how can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you show your query ?

Comment: check the question also I have tried avg() inside controller but I want it in model so that it would be efficient and easy

Comment: Yes but how you calculate the score now?

Comment: I haven't actually these are raw values which I got from db. now I need to calculate it from these values..

Comment: Can you provide your table structure for both the tables ?